# How do you transfer contacts from iPhone to Android phone?

Tags: android

Is there any ways that can transfer contacts from iPhone to Android (Samsung S6)?

Comment: This question is not related to SO

Comment: This question does not have anything to do with programming and belongs on android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Although this question doesn't belong here, just to guide you, you can use iCloud or Gmail for contacts transfer between iPhone and android. Here are the details [Contacts transfer](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-transfer-your-contacts-between-iphone-and-android/)

Point to be noted, from Next time don't post any non technical questions here.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently 3 ways to transfer content from iPhone to Android, each has its own pros and cons:

**Solution 1:  iCloud**

Export your contacts from iCloud] in vCard format and then copy that file to S6 , finally import it to your Galaxy S6 with Contacts app. It's free way but this is only limited to contacts transfer.

**Solution 2:  Mobile Apps**

There are a couple of apps( Zapya for example) being able to transfer standard content between different mobile devices such contacts, photos, etc... via wifi or bluetooth.

**Solution 3:  Desktop programs**

This sort of programs have the most powerful functions, which can be used to transfer all kind of content, such as contacts, sms, photos, music, ebooks etc... It takes only a few minutes to fully complete the transition from one mobile device to another. It's quite easy for beginners, demo tutorial can be seen from [here](http://www.androidphonesoft.com/resources/transfer-contacts-from-iphone-to-android-phone.html).

For contacts transfer only, the first suggestion is the best choice. For other content transfer, the later 2 suggestions are considerable.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

Login into contacts.google.com .
Then click on import tab.

Fill email password field from which you want to receive contact in your case Icloud ID

Then done

Your icloud contacts will be added in gmail

And you can easily take this in android